# Let $c = \{ x = \{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty} \in l^\infty \vert \exists \lim_{k \to \infty} x_k \in \mathbb{C} \}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $c = \{ x = \{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty} \in l^\infty \vert \exists \lim_{k \to \infty} x_k \in \mathbb{C} \}$.

Let $x_n \in c$, with $x_n \to x = \{x_k\}$ with the sup norm.

I want to prove that $ x \in c$.

So I am a bit stuck here, I want to use the fact that $x_n$ belongs to c, so it has a limit that I call $l_n$. But from now on I do not know how to keep going. Any help?

Comment: You should improve your notation: in your question, $x_k$ is sometimes a real number and sometimes an element in $c$. Maybe you should use $x^{k}$ for one or the other, which would enable notation such as $x_n^{k}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, you should improve your notation. It will help.

Let $(x_n)\subset c$ with $x_n=(x_n^1,x_n^2,\dots)$ for any $n$.

Let $x=(b_1,b_2,\dots)$. It suffices to prove that $(b_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

We have that $\|x_n-x\|_\infty\to0$, therefore $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}|x_n^k-b_k|=0}$. Let $\varepsilon>0$; then there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$ and for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ it is $|x_n^k-b_k|<\varepsilon$. Now since $x_{n_0}\in c$ it is a Cauchy sequence therefore for this $\varepsilon$ there exists $N\geq 0$ such that for all $m,n\geq N$ it is $|x_{n_0}^n-x_{n_0}^m|<\varepsilon$.

Now we have for $m,n\geq N$: $|b_n-b_m|\leq|b_n-x_{n_0}^n|+|x_{n_0}^n-x_{n_0}^m|+|x_{n_0}^m-b_m|<3\varepsilon$.

Since for a random $\varepsilon>0$ we have found an integer $N$ such that for all $m,n$ greater than $N$ it is $|b_n-b_m|<3\varepsilon$, by the definition of a Cauchy sequence we have that $(b_n)$ is Cauchy.

Comment: Good. I added a different style of proof.

Comment: Why is it enough to prove that the sequence is Cauchy? Moreover, why $x_{n_0}$ is Cauchy?

Comment: @qcc101 because a sequence of $\mathbb{C}$ is convergent if-f it is Cauchy; $x_{n_0}\in c$ and $c$ is by definition the space of convergent sequences.

Answer (score 1):

With the notation of the Answer given by JustDroppedIn.

Since you want to show that $c$ is closed in $l^{\infty},$ you can prove that $l^{\infty}\setminus c$ is open, as follows:

Let $x \in l^{\infty}\setminus c.$ Then $x$ is not a Cauchy sequence, so there exists $r>0,$ and  functions $f:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N,\, g:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N,$ both strictly increasing,  such that $$\forall k\in \Bbb N\,(\,|x^{f(k)}-x^{g(k)}|>r\,).$$ Consider the open ball $B(x,r/3)=\{y\in l^{\infty}: \|y-x\|<r/3\}.$ If $y\in B(x,r/3)$ then for all $k\in \Bbb N$ we have $$|y^{f(k)}-y^{g(k)}|=$$ $$=|(y^{f(k)}-x^{f(k)})+(x^{f(k)}-x^{g(k)})+(x^{g(k)}-y^{g(k)})|\geq$$ $$\geq -|y^{f(k)}-x^{f(k)}|+|x^{f(k)}-x^{g(k)}|-|x^{g(k)}-y^{g(k)}|\geq$$ $$\geq -\|y-x\|+|x^{f(k)}-x^{g(k)}|-\|x-y\|>$$ $$>-r/3+r-r/3=r/3.$$ Since $\{f(k):j\in \Bbb N\}$ and $\{g(k):k\in \Bbb N\}$ are infinite sets, this implies that any $y\in B(x,r/3)$ is not a Cauchy sequence.  So $B(x,r/3) \cap c =\emptyset.$

The idea is that you cannot uniformly approximate a non-convergent sequence $x$ to an arbitrary degree by a convergent sequence because of the "$r$". For a bounded non-convergent sequence $x$ we can take $0<r<(\lim \sup_{j\to \infty} x^j)-(\lim \inf_{j\to \infty} x^j).$